# javafx how to separate events of a StackPane and events of an element contained?

Tags: events, javafx

I have a StackPane containing several elements (Rectangles). I added an ActionEventHandler to all of them. I expect that when Rectangle object is clicked it starts anly the event added to its. Instead I see that both events are started, like I have pressed Rectangle and StackPane together. Here's the code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package provapanetile;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Ambra
 */
public class ProvaPaneTile extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {       

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        TilePane tp = new TilePane();
        tp.setVgap(10);
        tp.setHgap(10);

        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
            tp.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(50, 50, Color.AZURE));
        }            
        addListners(root, tp);
        root.getChildren().add(tp);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public void addListners(StackPane sp, TilePane tp){
        sp.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("You pressed StackPointer");
            }
        });
        tp.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("You pressed TilePane");
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Clicking ones on a Rectangle I get this 2 messagges:

```
You pressed TilePane
You pressed StackPointer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consume the event in the handler on the tile pane:

```
    tp.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("You pressed TilePane");
            event.consume();
        }
    });
```

Now when you click on the `TilePane`, only the handler registered with the tile pane will be invoked.

Note that in this example, the `TilePane` entirely covers the `StackPane`, so it's impossible to actually invoke the handler on the `StackPane`, which is probably not what you want. To fix that, you would need to manage the layout so that the `TilePane` did not grow to the full size of the `StackPane`; but obviously this is just an example to demonstrate the issue so perhaps this is enough for your real application...